# Select rows with a specific element from a given table

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation, data, dataset

Lets say I have 4 rows in

```
alist = {{1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 6}, {1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, x}, {1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 
    6}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, x}};
```

If I want to select and print out only the rows with the "x" from the previous one, i.e.,

```
{{1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, x}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, x}}
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Thank for clarify the question @Syed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Using `Select`:**

```
Select[alist, MemberQ[#, x] &]
```

**Using `Pick`:**

```
Pick[alist, MemberQ[#, x] & /@ alist]
```

**Using `Cases`:**

```
Cases[alist, {p___, x, q___}]
```

**Using `ContainsAny`**

```
Pick[alist, ContainsAny[#, {x}] & /@ alist]
```

or

```
Select[ContainsAny[{x}]][alist]
```

---

Result:

```
{{1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, x}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, x}}
```

Comment: This is perfect!!!! Now I can adjust a little bit and get what I want. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for the accept. I removed `Tableform` as you can apply it later to the results. Try to use `*Form` wrappers in general for display purposes only and not during computation.

Answer (score 3):

```
Select[alist,EqualTo[x]@*Last]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = 
  {{1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 6}, 
   {1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, x},
   {1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 6}, 
   {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, x}};
```

Using `ReplaceAll`

```
list /. {__?NumberQ} :> Nothing
```

> {{1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, x}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, x}}

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Catenate @ SequenceSplit[list, {{__, _?NumberQ}}]
```

> {{1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, x}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, x}}

Answer (score 1):

```
 list = 
  {{1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 6}, 
   {1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, x},
   {1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 6}, 
   {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, x}};
```

---

Using `DeleteCases`:

```
DeleteCases[list, {__?NumericQ}]
```

> `{{1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, x}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, x}}`

Or using `Replace` at level `1`:

```
Replace[list, {a__?NumericQ} :> Nothing, {1}]
```

> `{{1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, x}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, x}}`

Or using `ReplaceList`:

```
ReplaceList[list, {___, s : {p___, x, q___}, ___} :> s]
```

> `{{1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, x}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, x}}`